# BLE onServicesDiscovered() not returning characteristics array

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have implemented BLE central in my app. 
Steps :

1. Get BluetoothManager

   mBluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);

   mBluetoothAdapter = mBluetoothManager.getAdapter();
2. Scan for devices
3. Connect device

   mGatt = bluetoothDevice.connectGatt(this, false, gattCallback);
4. Handle callback and start service discovery

Once the device is connected I am making a call to discover services.

```
gatt.discoverServices();
```

Once the services are discovered I am catching it in

```
private final BluetoothGattCallback gattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        Log.i("onConnectionStateChange", "Status: " + status);
        switch (newState) {
            case BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED:
                Log.i("gattCallback", "STATE_CONNECTED");
                gatt.discoverServices();
                break;

            case BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                mGatt = null;
                mBluetoothSingleTonClass.saveGatt(mGatt);
                deviceDisconnected();
                Log.e("gattCallback", "STATE_DISCONNECTED");
                break;

            case BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTING :
                Log.e("gattCallback", "STATE_CONNECTING");
                break;

            default:
                Log.e("gattCallback", "STATE_OTHER");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {

        List<BluetoothGattService> services = new ArrayList<>();
        services.addAll(gatt.getServices());

        Log.d("onServicesDiscovered", "uuid::" + gatt.getServices().get(0).getUuid());
        Log.d("onServicesDiscovered", "uuid::" + gatt.getServices().get(1).getUuid());
        Log.d("onServicesDiscovered", "uuid::" + gatt.getServices().get(2).getUuid());

        Log.d("onServicesDiscovered", "chars::" + gatt.getServices().get(2).getCharacteristics().size());
        Log.d("onServicesDiscovered", "chars::" + gatt.getServices().get(0).getCharacteristics().size());
        Log.d("onServicesDiscovered", "chars::" + gatt.getServices().get(1).getCharacteristics().size());


    }
};
```

The problem is **gatt** gives me all the services the device has, but it is giving empty characteristics array in few mobile. 
Example: `gatt.getServices().get(0).getCharacteristics().size()`
This was working fine in Nexus but after few days it is giving me empty array i.e size is zero. 
Am I doing anything wrong? Is this the problem with the mobile? Any reference links would be helpful.

Comment: attach your code

Answer (score 0):

It may give an empty (or too short) list if the device disconnects during the discovery procedure. You should check the status code in the callback and only assume the services are valid if it is 0 (SUCCESS).

Comment: Yes I checked that also. if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered success: " + status);
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered failure: " + status);
            }It is giving 0

Comment: In that case things the phone's Bluetooth stack might be buggy. You should check the HCI snoop log to see if services are reported correctly, but the stack later reports the incorrect services.

Comment: I am getting the proper services. Issue is with the characteristic ids. It is giving 0. Also it takes more time to connect to peripheral. Is there a solution for this ?

Answer (score -1):

delay 600ms to call gatt.discoverServices() resolve this pr